# how to create breadcrumbs with anchor form url in php

Tags: php

for a filemanagement system  i want to create some breadcrumbs in php from the url.
The root directory for each user is looks like this in the url:

```
example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root
```

In the rootdir there is a folder named `folder1`
When clicking on folder1, the url is:

```
example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1
```

In folder1 there is a folder named `folder2`
When clicking on that folder, the url becomes:

```
example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1/folder2
```

and so on...
How can i make some breadcrumbs with anchor to the folders based on the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, what you want to do is take the contends of `$_GET['dir']` and split them up by `/`, then provide links to each of them.

Here is how I would do it:

```
$crumbs=explode('/',$_GET['dir']); // this splits the sections of $_GET['dir'] separated by / into an array of values
$url_pre=''; // we'll use this to keep track of the crumbs we've sifted through already

// foreach cycles through each element in an array
// $crumbs is the array, and $crumb is the current listing in the array we're looking at
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    $url_pre .= $crumb;
    echo '<a href="?dir='.$url_pre.'">'.$crumb.'</a>';
    $url_pre .= '/'; // add this after you echo the link, so that dir doesn't start with a /
}
```

Comment: Tested it and it works great!! Thank you for this solution. (little typo: `$url_pre.=.$crumb;` should be `$url_pre.= $crumb;`)